# Performance of MDX Qyery working fine for one year, how can we run same query for two year

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Performance of  MDX Qyery working fine for one year, how can we run same query for two year

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[Metric] AS Round(sum(({[Year].[Year].&[2015]}),[Measures].[PurchaseSum]),2)
SET CustYear as exists([DIMCustomer].[Level 02].allmembers,({[Year].[Year].&[2015]}),"sales")              
  SET [BusinessSet] AS { filter((    
              EXISTS(CustYear, [DIMCustomer].[HierarchyCategory].&[UnitHierarchy],"sales")
     ),([Measures].[Metric] or [Measures].[Metric]=0) )}

  SET [SellerFilterCustomerID] AS EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,{[DIMSeller].[CustId].[All]}, "sales")
  SET [SellerFilterCustomerType] AS  EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,[DIMSeller].[CustomerType].[All])
  SET [SellerFilterCompanyName] AS EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,{[DIMSeller].[Name].[All]},  "sales")
  SET [SellerFilterCompanyLoc] AS EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,[DIMSeller].[Organization].[All])
  SET [FinalSellerFilter] as (intersect(intersect(intersect([SellerFilterCustomerID],[SellerFilterCustomerType]),[SellerFilterCompanyName]),[SellerFilterCompanyLoc]))
  SET Name     AS  {[DIMCustomer].[Name].[All]}
  SET Code    AS  {[DIMCustomer].[Code].[All]}
  SET CustType    AS  {[DIMCustomer].[CustomerType].[All]}
  SET OrgLoc      AS  {[DIMCustomer].[Organization].[All]}
  SET CustFilters AS (Name,Code,CustType,OrgLoc)     
  SET ICP as {{[DimProduct].[ICP].[All]}}
  SET ProdICP as (ICP)

  //creating year filter
  SET CrYear as  {[Year].[Year].&[2015]}


  SET Others AS (CrYear,ProdICP)   
  SET [SalesSet] AS exists([BusinessSet],[FinalSellerFilter],"sales")
  //creating final set
  SET FINALSET as exists([SalesSet],CustFilters,"sales" )
  SET Geo as exists([DIMCustomer].[ParentPostalNumber].[ParentPostalNumber],({[Year].[Year].&[2015]}),"sales")
  SET [FIPS] AS  Except(EXISTS(Geo,[SalesSet], "sales"),{[DIMCustomer].[ParentPostalNumber].&[0],[DIMCustomer].[ParentPostalNumber].&[]})

  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales] AS round(sum(([FINALSET],Others),[Measures].[Metric]),2)

  MEMBER [Measures].[Count] as  (exists(([FINALSET],Others,[SalesType].[SalesType].&[3]),[DIMCustomer].[ParentPostalNumber].currentmember, "sales")).count
SELECT
non empty  {
 [Measures].[Sales],[Measures].[Count]  
  } ON 0,
  NON EMPTY{
    FIPS
  } ON 1
FROM [cube]**
```

Comment: we really need a fuller explanation of what is required.

Comment: This is ONE BIG MESSED UP query! Couple of things. 1. Avoid named set as much as possible. Try to push the calculations to creation of `MEMBER`. 2. Try putting in `NonEmpty` wherever possible. 3. Try avoiding `NON EMPTY` unless really required. 4. Get rid of the sets in the script which are not getting used down in the final query. Also I can't still understand the reasoning behind ` EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,{[DIMSeller].[Name].[All]},  "sales")`. Why are you having it?

Answer (score 0):

To run it for 2 years just swap all instances of this:

```
{[Year].[Year].&[2015]}
```

for this...

```
{[Year].[Year].&[2014], [Year].[Year].&[2015]}
```

Partitioning in your warehouse is most likely to be the cause - the `Exists` function refers back to the fact tables. Although maybe you can avoid using `Exists` in this sort of context and find an alternative:

```
EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,{[DIMSeller].[CustId].[All]}, "sales")
```

Sourav has noticed that you might be using `EXISTS` instead of `NonEmpty` - if you can use the later function as it is more efficient.

Comment: alerady i test it will running in 20 min. this is a problem.

Comment: but for just one year it runs quickly?

Comment: still not working, i am removing exists and partition as well.

Comment: @whytheq - JUst curious. What does `EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS,{[DIMSeller].[CustId].[All]}, "sales")` imply? Can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I think it is the same as just this statement `[DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS` ....? Not sure why the `EXISTS` function has been included

Comment: Hmm..Customers with sales -- >`EXISTS([DIMSeller].[CustId].ALLMEMBERS, ,"sales")` The earlier `EXISTS` made non sense at all

Comment: ahh, ok, if that is the case sourav then the user should 100% switch to `NonEmpty`

Comment: This is required for creating seller set. if a customer pass a parameter for customer type  then we  need  only customer type customer id in intersect function.